# Adding rasters to mosaic dataset from CSV list using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, csv, error-000732, mosaic-dataset

I have a CSV list containing paths to 800 TIFF files that I want to add to a mosaic dataset.

So using the Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset tool, I need to create a loop which changes the input_path variable based on a list derived from the CSV. The CSV paths are formatted as follows -

D:\Docs\111\Name_of_Raster.tif

Looking at the documentation (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-rasters-to-mosaic-dataset.htm), I've copied the stand alone script and converted the CSV to a Python list but am lost how to actually link the two together.

```
import arcpy,os,csv

arcpy.env.workspace = 'D:\'
md = 'D:\Map.gdb\Mosaic'

with open('D:\Mosaic_list.csv') as mosaic_csv:
        reader = csv.reader(mosaic_csv, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        mosaic_list = list(reader)
        print(mosaic_list)

for row in mosaic_list:
    arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(in_mosaic_dataset = md, raster_type = 'Raster Dataset',  input_path = row)
```

The above code results in - ERROR 000732: Input Data: Dataset Path does not exist or is not supported.

Is my approach correct or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: How the paths are organized inside the CSV file? It is better to add a sample of the CSV file into your question.

Comment: Have you tried testing on `arcpy.Exists()` during list assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Vince and ahmadhanb  for the guidance. I was convinced the issue was with my lack of my python skills but I went back to square one and looked at my data after and found the first row of my CSV was 'pathname' and was the cause of the error.